# Why it is normal to inject BeanFactory to Spring component but isn't to Spring Bean?

Tags: java, spring

Currently I watch a lecture(not in English) where lecturer claims that this is normal to inject [`BeanFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html) into a Spring internal component. His example is:

```
public class PostProxyInvokerContextListener implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
    @Autowired
    private ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory;

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        ...
    }
}
```

He also says that it isn't normal to insert [`ApplicationContext`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationContext.html) or [`BeanFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html) into regular bean created by programmer.

I understand why we should avoid this for regular beans(tight coupling) but I don't understand why the rule isn't applied for spring components.

Comment: Spring components are already part of spring framework therefore already have that coupling that you are trying to avoid in your beans. That said, if you know that you are not going to have another framework for DI, you can, if need be, use spring's `BeanFactory` implementation injected in your code.

Comment: @Prashant so the coupling in the case is that Spring component depends on spring component is normal because our application doesn't care about it but if the application depends on Spring component this is bad and unscalable. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, however for most enterprise applications are dependent on one framework or the other (or even more than one frameworks). So say for example, if you are using Spring framework, you will see code making use of `@Autowired` rather than `@Inject`. Using `@Autowired` any ways brings in spring dependency. Hooking into the lifecycle method calls just makes your application more dependent as it is easy to replace `@Autowired` with `@Inject` but difficult to remove business logic from the hook methods (or callbacks)

Comment: @Prashant thank you for your help! I think you should organize these thoughts into answer and I will accept it with pleasure.

Comment: Ok, I will. Please give me some time to create scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different Spring projects use Spring dependencies. Its not entirely correct to say that we should not be using Spring components like `ApplicationContext` if we know that we are not going to move away from using Spring framework. For example, if we know that the web application that we are working on is not going to be migrated from Spring to Struts (no one does this anyways), we can inject `ApplicationContext`. Say we have created a custom annotation `@ApplyControl` which applies a set of checks (different types of checks) using `AOP`, we can use `ListableBeanFactory` to list out all the classes marked `@Control` and put them in a map based registry and then pull out the control to be applied in the advice. If we compare between `JPA` and `Hibernate`, the `JPA` standard provides us with a set of annotations that are implemented by any ORM, so in such cases, we can stick with JPA based annotation making our application independent of Hibernate and any such implementation. This is not the same case with Spring - I have hardly seen anyone using Spring with `@Inject`. That said, using `ListableBeanFactory` or any other such implementation provided by spring should only be used if there is no other easier way of achieving the use case.